# $n$-fold product is a morphism of coalgebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

Let $(H,\mu,\eta,\Delta,\varepsilon)$ be a bialgebra with antipode $S$ which is cocommutative. On $\text{End}(H)$ we have the product $$f\ast g:=\mu\circ(f\otimes g)\circ\Delta\in\text{End}(H).$$

Using this (and the cocommutativity) I want to show that $\text{id}_H^{\ast n+1}$ is a coalgebra morphism. Any thoughts?

Comment: Where do you get stuck? This seems to be essentially immediate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just follows from a direct calculation. The map is $f:x\in H\mapsto x_1\cdots x_n\in H$.

Now 
\begin{align}
\Delta(f(x))&=(x_1\cdots x_n)_1\otimes(x_1\cdots x_n)_2\\
&=(x_1)_1\cdots (x_n)_1\otimes (x_1)_2\cdots (x_n)_2\\
&= x_1x_3\cdots x_{2n-1}\otimes x_2x_4\cdots x_{2n}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
(f\otimes f)(\Delta(x))
&= f(x_1)\otimes f(x_2) \\
&= (x_1)_1\cdots (x_1)_n\otimes (x_2)_1\cdots (x_2)_n \\
&= x_1\cdots x_n\otimes x_{n+1}\cdots x_{2n}
\end{align}
and these two things are equal simply because of cocommutativity.

Comment: If you like you can add the big sigmas: they serve no real purpose ;-) what 2nd and 2rd equalities. Everything which is not the definition of the maps here is just coassociativity, cocommutativity and the compatibility of the product and the copr

Comment: 2 is the compatibility of the product and the coproduct.

Comment: 3 coassociativity.

Comment: 6 coassociativity again.